# Extracting parts of filenames from an array

Tags: beginner, regex, file-system, perl

I am very new to perl. So far I love it, my new favorite interpreted language. I am quickly learning that perl has MANY 'tricks' to it. The following code extracts file names out of one array and into another using a simple regex. Is there a shorter way of doing this?

It feels like there's a way to remove the for loop.

```
my @configs = glob("m4/config.*.m4");
my @outputs;

foreach(@configs)
{
    $_ =~ m/m4\/(config\..*)\.m4/;
    push @outputs, $1;
}


print join(' ',@configs) . "\n";
# m4/config.a2.m4 m4/config.mk.m4 m4/config.php.m4

print join(' ',@outputs) . "\n";
# config.a2 config.mk config.php

exit;
```

Comment: It's worrying that you think of any parts of Perl as being a "trick". Some facilities, such as built-in regex patterns, may be unfamiliar to you, but if you really think that something is a "trick" in any way then you should consider coding it differently.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As said before, use map instead of a foreach loop and change the regex delimiter.

If you put the array in double quote when print, a space is inserted between each element of the array in fact it is the content of the special variable `$"`, see http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html

> $LIST_SEPARATOR
> $"
>
> When an array or an array slice is interpolated into a double-quoted string or a similar context such as /.../ , its elements are separated by this value. Default is a space. For example, this:
>
> ```
>    print "The array is: @array\n";
> ```
>
> is equivalent to this:
>
> ```
>    print "The array is: " . join($", @array) . "\n";
> ```
>
> Mnemonic: works in double-quoted context.

Your code becomes:

```
# Use ALLWAYS these two lines in every script.
use strict;
use warnings;

my @configs = glob("m4/config.*.m4");
my @outputs = map{ m~m4/(config\..*)\.m4$~ } @configs;
print "@configs\n";
print "@outputs\n";
```

**Output:**

```
m4/config.a2.m4 m4/config.mk.m4 m4/config.php.m4
config.a2 config.mk config.php
```

Comment: `my @outputs = map{ m~m4/(config\..*)\.m4$~ } @configs;` will give empty list in case regex doesn't match (even when you're sure it always will)

Comment: @mpapec: True but if it doesn't match, I guess it's correct to return nothing.

Comment: Yes, but in your case map will always return $1, regardless of unsuccessful match.

Comment: @mpapec: Ok, I see. corrected.

Comment: Wow, this is pure wizardry. Great work.

Comment: @SanchkeDellowar: Please don't think in terms of "magic", "tricks", and "wizardry". The best code is both concise and clear, and something that isn't immediately obvious should have been written differently. It isn't clever to confuse and baffle people, and artefacts such as the [*Perl secret operators and constants*](http://search.cpan.org/dist/perlsecret/lib/perlsecret.pod) are a disgrace to CPAN. The `map` function in conjunction with a pattern match is standard Perl.

Comment: @Toto: The result of `$1 if m~m4/(config\..*)\.m4$~` is officially *the value returned by the last expression evaluated* if the match fails. You could use a conditional expression to provide a value in either case `m~m4/(config\..*)\.m4$~ ? $1 : ()` or you could simply use the value returned by the regex, as **mpapec** says.

Comment: @Borodin: You're right, I've forgotten that, thank you. Answer edited.

Comment: @Toto: The truth is that the *last expression evaluated* is the regex pattern match, which returns an empty list because it contains a capture. That means the result is actually what you wanted, but for reasons which are less than clear!

Answer (score 4):

The Perl command that you want is [`map`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html).  I don't have time to work up a test, so I won't try to write the code.  You may find this [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3652527/6660678) relevant, although it is doing something slightly different.

A few other quick comments

> ```
> foreach(@configs)
> {
>     $_ =~ m/m4\/(config\..*)\.m4/;
> ```

A more common way to write this is

```
foreach my $config (@configs)
{
    $config =~ m{m4/(config\..*)\.m4};
```

Because the regex contains a `/`, you don't want to use that as the delimiter.  I prefer the `{}` delimiters.  Perl will take almost anything though.  E.g. `#` instead of `/` is one common alternative.

I prefer to declare a variable rather than use the default `$_`.

Note that

```
    m{m4/(config\..*)\.m4};
```

is the same as saying

```
    $_ =~ m{m4/(config\..*)\.m4};
```

The `$_` is the default both for the `foreach` and for the regular expression.  So you normally wouldn't write it out here.  If you want to be extra explicit, declaring the variable with `my` is even better.

Comment: I very much disagree. Perl provides `$_` for precisely this purpose, and there is no need for the noise of declaring and comparing `$config`. There is also no need to write `foreach` when `for` is identical.